# CompletionHandler Closure Variable In Swift 3 Protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

I have a protocol which holds 1 function and 1 variable which will be used as a completion handler from different points of the class that will conform to this protocol.

```
@objc protocol Presentor : class {
  @objc optional var completionHandler:()->Void {get set}
  func presentScreen:(screenName:String, completion:()->Void)
}
```

I am using extension to provide common implementation like so:

```
extension Presentor where Self:UIViewController{
  func presentScreen:(screenName:String, completion:()->Void){
  self.completionHandler = completion
}
```

Basically i would prefer to keep the completion private because the `UIViewController` that will confonrm to this protocol should not interact with it.

Swift complains that `Property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannit be represented in Objective-C`
It complains about the closure. I marked this protocol as `@objc` because I want to set the `completionHandler` to be optional.